# Why does the number of edits decrease when the edited post is deleted?

Tags: discussion, edits

I am new to Stack Overflow. So I don't know why the number of edits is decreased when an edited post is deleted in Stack Overflow. Recently I edited one post and get +2 reputation but suddenly I lost it. When I checked why my reputation is cut, the counter of edited post is decreased. Can anyone explain how the edit counter works?

Comment: If the post is no longer around then everything that happened because of that post no longer happened which means the edits no longer happened.

Comment: You should avoid editing crap, especially new crap. It annoys reviewers sometimes too. I suggest that you focus on things that are unlikely to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty self-explanatory.

When the edited thing was deleted, everything about it ceased to exist, including the fact that you'd edited it.

Votes are also "undone" when this happens.

Comment: Interesting how that works. Is there some sort of design reason for this, like refunding down-vote karma?

Comment: @JeremyKato: For something to be deleted, it should never have existed in the first place, so nobody deserves any rep from voting on or editing it.